# Recover missing files on an external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I backed up my files from the office in my external hard drive couple of days ago. The files are from a Mac. Then after I went home I checked the files and the files were there. After that I accidentally placed my tablet—which has magnets, nvidia shield—on top of it for 2 hours without realizing the effect on it.

When I plug in on my Mac at home it can’t detect the external hard drive. Then I plug it on Windows and it said that my hard drive needs to be scan and fix it. I click it then it finally detects my external drive but now I can’t find the files that I backed up from the office couple of days ago.

I tried using [Recurva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) but it still not showing the files or do I need to set some options in recurva for thorough scan? Is there a way that I can recover my missing files?

Comment: It's hard to believe that a small magnet would affect a modern HDD (though I do have a 20-kg-pull Nd-B magnet that might). More likely the error is from *improperly closed* files. You might try routine disk repair, and if there are no additional *unrecoverable sectors*, the error was not from the magnet.

Comment: My dad also used the "scan fix" button on windows when it appeared when he plugged his flash drive and it wiped all its contents. I think that the "scan fix" from windows is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but you most probably deleted everything when you ran Scan and fix on the Windows machine. If the data is important for you might consider using the services of a data recovery company, although I'm not completely sure if the can help a lot in this case.